# sql query needs input from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where i want the data from two tables, they look something like this:

```
categories:    entries:
+----+------+  +----+-------------+-------+-------------+
| id | name |  | ID | category_id | title | description |
+----+------+  +----+-------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 |  foo |  |  1 |      1      |  bar  | Loreum ip.. |
+----+------+  +----+-------------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to get info from `entries`, and my input will just be category name and entry title. It does obviously work if i use two statements. something like:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `name` = 'foo' LIMIT 1;
SELECT `ID`, `category_id`, `title`, `description` FROM `entries` WHERE `title` = 'bar' AND `category_id` = $cat_id LIMIT 1;
```

Where `$cat_id` is the output from the first entry. But i want to combine these to into one statement, and i don't find join useful here? So my question is basically how can i combine these into one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join concept like i suggest

```
SELECT `ID`, `category_id`, `title`, `description` FROM `entries` 
inner join  `categories` on `entries`.`category_id`=`categories`.`id`
WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'foo' AND `title` = 'bar'  LIMIT 1;
```

Seems you look new, please explore concept about sql

Comment: I ended up with this `SELECT et.ID as 'id’, et.title as ‘title’, et.description as description FROM entries as et left join categories as cat on cat.id=sn.category_id WHERE et.title = ? AND cat.name = ? LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables together and filter as you need.

```
select e.*
from entries e
join categories c on e.category_id = c.id
where e.title = 'bar'
    and c.name = 'foo'
order by ??  -- important when using "limit"
limit 1;
```

Also, to get consistent one row, you should add an `order by` clause with proper column(s) to the query. If you want just any one row, then you may use without it.

To exactly do what you are doing, you can use subquery:

```
select *
from entries
where category_id in (
        select id
        from categories
        where name = 'foo'
        limit 1
        )
    and title = 'bar'
    limit 1;
```

But remember that without `order by` clause, you may get inconsistent results from `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

May be the only way is to use subquery. though I don't way it is a good way.

```
    SELECT `ID`, `category_id`, `title`, `description` FROM `entries` WHERE `title` = 'bar' 
AND `category_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `name` = 'foo' LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1;
```